# How to drag one viewpager withrespect to another view pager in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe, drag

I have two view pager in a Same fragment. Both have same number of Items.
My Need is When I Swipe a view pager the other view pager also need to swipe and vice Versa. How Can I implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an `OnPageChangeListener` to the first `ViewPager`.

In `onPageScrollStateChanged()`, when the state is `SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING`, call `beginFakeDrag()` on the other `ViewPager`.  When the state is idle or settling, call `endFakeDrag()` on the other `ViewPager`.

In `onPageScrolled()`, call `fakeDragBy()` on the other `ViewPager`.  You may need to do some tracking, as `onPageScrolled()` with report an absolute position, and `fakeDragBy()` is cumulative.